# Is there a way to search a corresponding column based on specific criteria? Excel

Tags: r, excel

I want to ask excel to search in a list (column) to see if the value in a specific cell appears. I then want to search the values next to these matches (in the next column) to see if a different specific cell content appears in these adjacent cells. I expect the result to be TRUE or FALSE.

As an example:

Do the contents of E1 appear in H:H next to contents of A23 in G:G.

Sample image

[image: 1]

Thanks in advance.

I am open to trying it in R but suspect it will be easer in excel as the drag function will make adjusting the values easier.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` of `INDEX/MATCH`?

Answer (score 0):

So... I created a list then used countif function on that list.

the list constructed:
q4 = the variable I wanted to look for.
column A has the matching variable to q4 in in it
column c has the variable I wanted listed next to q4 .

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Q4=$A$3:$A$67,$C$3:$C$67,""))